# Warning: Unused local variable: bool

Tags: solidity

```
contract Puzzle {
     address payable public owner ;
     bool public locked ;
     uint public reward ;
     bytes32 public diff ;
     bytes public solution ;


     /*constructor () payable public {*/
     constructor ( ) payable public{
     owner = msg.sender ;
     reward = msg.value ;
     locked = false ;
     /* Error:diff = bytes32 (11111); */ // pre - defined difficulty
     diff = bytes32 (uint256(11111));
  }

  function () payable external{ // main code , runs at every invocation
    if ( msg. sender == owner ){ // update reward
       //if ( locked )
       //throw ;
       require(!locked);
       bool val=owner.send ( reward );
       reward = msg.value ;
    }
    else
    if ( msg . data . length > 0){ // submit a solution
        require(!locked);
       //if ( locked ) throw ;
          if ( sha256 (msg. data ) < diff ){
             bool val=msg. sender . send ( reward ); // send reward
             solution = msg. data ;
             locked = true ;
       }}}}
```

I am getting following warning message:

> > solc puzzle_sha256.sol puzzle_sha256.sol:39:8: Warning: Unused local variable.
> >            bool val=owner.send ( reward );
> >            ^------^ puzzle_sha256.sol:47:14: Warning: Unused local variable.
> >                  bool val=msg. sender . send ( reward ); // send reward
> >                  ^------^

Some body please guide me how to remove the warning. Also please check if I have used the require correctly or not.

Zulfi.

Comment: You can remove the warning by... using that variable. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bool val=owner.send ( reward );

Let's rewrite as

`bool success = owner.send(reward);`

Now, it says `success` is unused.

You can go:

```
bool success = owner.send(reward);
require(success, "The send failed.");
```

or

```
require(owner.send(reward), "The send failed.");
```

or

`owner.transfer(reward); // reverts on fail`

or, if this blog freaks you out (hat tip to Steve) https://diligence.consensys.net/posts/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/

then,

```
bool success;
bytes memory response;
(success, response) = msg.sender.call.value(reward)(""); // send reward
require(success, "The send failed.");
```

Hope it helps.